# Invalid Or Unqualified Reference at: lastRA = .Range("A2" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Tags: vba, excel

Why do I receive the following error

> Invalid or Unqualified reference"

at this line: `lastRA = .Range("A2" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` with `.Rows` highlighted?

```
Sub HighlightUpgrds()
    Dim lastRA As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim linecount As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range

    linecount = 2
    Set ws = Worksheets("Walk Ups")
    Set rng1 = Cells(linecount, "N")
    Set rng2 = Cells(linecount, "O")
    lastRA = .Range("A2" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRA
        If Cells(linecount, "N") <> Cells(linecount, "O") Then
            Cells(linecount, "N").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 64)
            Cells(linecount, "O").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 64)
        Else
        End If
        linecount = linecount + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `lastRA = .Range("A2" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` into

```
lastRA = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Or put a `With ws` … `End With` around it:

```
With ws
    lastRA = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

You should always fully qualify your cells/ranges:
Also the others in your code like `Cells(linecount, "N")` should be qualified to the worksheet e.g. `ws.Cells(linecount, "N")`

Comment: I appreciate your help. I have changed the line to:

Comment: I have changed the line to:lastRA = ws.Range("A2" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row but now I receive the error MethodRange of Object_ Worksheet failed.

Comment: You might want to double-check that 
Range("A2" & ws.Rows.Count) gives you a correct range reference. Perhaps it should be Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count) (without 2) ?

Comment: @RADO of course, should have seen that. corrected it to `A` instead of `A2` @anthony please try the corrected answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the following approach...

```
Sub HighlightUpgrds()
    Dim lastRA As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim linecount As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range

    linecount = 2
    Set ws = Worksheets("Walk Ups")
    Set rng1 = ws.Cells(linecount, "N")
    Set rng2 = ws.Cells(linecount, "O")
    lastRA = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRA
        If ws.Cells(linecount, "N") <> ws.Cells(linecount, "O") Then
            ws.Cells(linecount, "N").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 64)
            ws.Cells(linecount, "O").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 64)
        Else
        End If
        linecount = linecount + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

**OR**

```
Sub HighlightUpgrds()
    Dim lastRA As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim linecount As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range

    linecount = 2
    Set ws = Worksheets("Walk Ups")
    With ws
        Set rng1 = .Cells(linecount, "N")
        Set rng2 = .Cells(linecount, "O")
        lastRA = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lastRA
            If .Cells(linecount, "N") <> .Cells(linecount, "O") Then
               .Cells(linecount, "N").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 64)
               .Cells(linecount, "O").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 64)
            Else
            End If
            linecount = linecount + 1
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried your second approach but now I receive the following error: Method 'Range' Of Object_'Worksheet' failed at this line lastRA = .Range("A2" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  Why do I now receive this error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @sktneer you oversaw the same issue like me ^^ It should be `.Range("A" & .Rows.Count)` instead of `.Range("A2" & .Rows.Count)` to give a valid range object.

Comment: @Peh Haha that's interesting. I never expected that error. Will edit it accordingly. Lol

Comment: @Anthony try the edited solution and let me know if that works for you now.